# html dialog element animation with framer

Tags: html, reactjs, animation, framer-motion, html5dialog

i have an <motion.dialog> element and i am humbling with doing animation but it isn't working
this is the element

```
<motion.dialog onClick={closeModal} className={className}
            initial={{insetBlockStart:"500px"}}
            animate={{insetBlockStart:"0px"}}
        >
```

when click the open button

```
 const eventModalHandle=()=>{
      setEventModal(true);
      document.querySelector(`.event-modal`).showModal();
  }
```

this is the way the open modal but animation it is not working i don't want to do it with div

test modal this is the browser result after opening but it is not animating

Answer (score 0):

We are the same . But I am here for exit animation not working . So this is how I animate enter animation in React with Framer Motion .

```
const [togglereactionList, settogglereactionList] = useState(false);
const SocialDialog = useRef<HTMLDialogElement>(null);

useEffect(() => {
togglereactionList
  ? SocialDialog.current?.showModal()
  : SocialDialog.current?.close();
  }, [togglereactionList]);
```

JSX

```
<AnimatePresence mode="wait">
    {togglereactionList && (
    <motion.dialog
    initial={{ opacity: 0, y: 300 }}
    transition={{ duration: 1 }}
    animate={{
        opacity: togglereactionList ? 1 : 0,
        y: togglereactionList ? 0 : 300,
    }}
    ref={SocialDialog}
    onClose={(e) => {
          settogglereactionList((prev) => !prev);              
    }}
</motion.dialog>
)}
  </AnimatePresence>
```